# Using Chart JS in Asp.net MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a table having no of files and their month. i want to show line chart for progress of every month. but i am not able to show the data in the chart,
in console.log date is also not in the required form. how should i put month names which are generated from the sql query on label fields and and every month counting of file on the data

```
DataSet ds = dbop.GetViews();
            List<ListReg> list = new List<ListReg>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                list.Add(new ListReg
                {
                    eFile_registered = Convert.ToInt32(dr["eFile_registered"]),
                    eFile_Month = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["eFile_Month"]).ToString()
                });

            }

            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`


//model

  $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/test/LineChart",
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (dr) {
                    console.log(dr);
                    var month=dr[0];
                    var count=dr[1];

                    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
                    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        height: "230px",
                        width: "300px",
                        responsive: false,
                        animation: false,
                        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                        data: {
                            //labels: ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"],  
                            labels: month,
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'Monthly Expenses',
                                data: count,
                                backgroundColor: "rgb(66, 134, 244)"
                            }]
                        }, options: {
                            events: ['click'],
                            scaleShowValues: true,
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true
                                    }
                                }],
                                xAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        autoSkip: false
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });


                },
                "error": function (list) {
                    alert("Some Error Occured!");
                }
            });
        })
```

Comment: Can you provide example contents of `List<ListReg>` so that we can reproduce your issue? What thing doesn't work and what kind of expected result you want to achieve?

Comment: {efile: 239, month:january},{efile: 309, month:february},{efile: 319, month:march}. i want to show this data in line chart

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto bro you have solved my issue before as well, can u take remote connection if possible